# what's the meaning of good at in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage

He inserted an ad in a few towns with a coupon, good at any store for a package of the new-style product.

He inserted an ad in a few towns with a coupon, good at any store for a package of the new-style product.

I don't undrestand the meaning of "good at" in that sentence.It would be more appreciated if you could give a full explanation of the above sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One of the senses of “good” is “valid”.

“good at” tells you *where* the coupon is valid.

Related is “good for”, which tells you either *when* the coupon is valid or *what* the coupon is valid for, depending on the following expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly US (American) usage, and you can consider 'good for' to mean 'valid to be exchanged or used for'. If you go to a store and your ticket is 'good' for one package of the product, you give the shopkeeper the coupon, and he or she gives you one package. If it says 'good for two packages', you get two packages, and so on. If it is 'good at' a store or stores you can use it at those stores.

If a bus ticket says 'good for one journey' then you can't use it more than once.

> good for in American English
>
> 1. able to survive, endure, or be used for (a specified period of time)
> 2. worth
>    a coupon good for 10¢

[Good for (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/good-for)